# AWS-Lambda: How to deal with SNS event in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

**How do I get bucket name from the SNS event?**

A S3 bucket publishes an event to a SNS topic. This topic triggers a Lambda. I need SNS because some other process also listen to this event. So I can't directly trigger Lambda from S3.

In lambda function I get two parameters: `event` and `context`
I need to get the bucket name out of the event. I was expecting to do something like this:

```
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
```

But this is not working because according to Cloudwatch, the event parameter looks like this:

```
{
    "Records":[
        {
            "EventSource":"aws:sns",
            "EventVersion":"1.0",
            "EventSubscriptionArn":"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1:823baaf4-93b6-499a-944e-c99e1a6b1fb5",
            "Sns":{
                "Type":"Notification",
                "MessageId":"2330809c-29c4-5826-910d-d64a7ab22247",
                "TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1",
                "Subject":"None",
                "Message":"{\\'Records\\': [{\\'EventSource\\': \\'aws:sns\\', \\'EventVersion\\': \\'1.0\\', \\'EventSubscriptionArn\\': \\'arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1:823baaf4-93b6-499a-944e-c99e1a6b1fb5\\', \\'Sns\\': {\\'Type\\': \\'Notification\\', \\'MessageId\\': \\'b611d3b2-a0d4-55fe-af0f-85648ffc2a59\\', \\'TopicArn\\': \\'arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1\\', \\'Subject\\': \\'None\\', \\'Message\\': \\'{\\n   \"Records\":[\\n      {\\n         \"EventSource\":\"aws:sns\",\\n         \"EventVersion\":\"1.0\",\\n         \"EventSubscriptionArn\":\"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1:823baaf4-93b6-499a-944e-c99e1a6b1fb5\",\\n         \"Sns\":{\\n            \"Type\":\"Notification\",\\n            \"MessageId\":\"906fd69c-ee31-50f2-8b9d-804910f6fdcd\",\\n            \"TopicArn\":\"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1\",\\n            \"Subject\":\"Amazon S3 Notification\",\\n            \"Message\":\"{\\\\\"Service\\\\\":\\\\\"Amazon S3\\\\\",\\\\\"Event\\\\\":\\\\\"s3:TestEvent\\\\\",\\\\\"Time\\\\\":\\\\\"2020-03-01T18:18:46.898Z\\\\\",\\\\\"Bucket\\\\\":\\\\\"s3-dam-poc-dev-inbox\\\\\",\\\\\"RequestId\\\\\":\\\\\"9534F72BD9216CA8\\\\\",\\\\\"HostId\\\\\":\\\\\"hSPdeBzns8wjrMHqkFJgw1UPMv0aZ/VOsAxw/z9wtboR+TOy8sKSKElDYxm9kszokgPsBU9T1nU=\\\\\"}\",\\n            \"Timestamp\":\"2020-03-01T18:18:47.036Z\",\\n            \"SignatureVersion\":\"1\",\\n            \"Signature\":\"FuoBKJczUXuKJ58d5SdddqnOjMwjxzG2aN+sef/0M5MFsAjRMyCNknvaXVVRrhujK39HouoOoDqyJNFzDWYR3WTYAM0Sqws9wJK9zBV9mxmMYdIurfDmVj4xsF4xuSeaMy4y/VfU2r75DxqhE3MPmA02IuGInGJsmw9CTk+Ao+kdnk/6rJT+Bt3EKK7uKj3kIWYehPDCYKYdzCsDcaP+Aaj2qEhEbkZxdaopB+pHRkMsLhZS/vHcc0Vd1eyZkRYHkxrG4FeKXVZdJT5OGuyixOSWq9YdCBJhWRnq7cRlQnk05WfswWdukOw9yjBkidsT1pJoiBQ==\",\\n            \"SigningCertUrl\":\"https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-a86cb10b4e1f29c941702d7371d28f7b6.pem\",\\n            \"UnsubscribeUrl\":\"https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1:823baaf4-93b6-499a-944e-c99e1a6b1fb5\",\\n            \"MessageAttributes\":{\\n\\n            }\\n         }\\n      }\\n   ]\\n}\\', \\'Timestamp\\': \\'2020-03-01T21:45:12.192Z\\', \\'SignatureVersion\\': \\'1\\', \\'Signature\\': \\'pt7Mkfo+CB5rsHAnWWB7Kb/LtgBCZSJWc2fLTB84FhZ9/MFUK0pOYmou97dAgn1hdo48JEXnQKpnMN5flmxwGEmG6SPHklnSAgE18a0Bv0qQgzQ1KF9PIY2ulRJiebbuE0gToTlDCgiUGd0OJpZ5Cdr4TSZgOpT4AcDD4NcpGCBKMTRwTcllaQDTNWF2mko9y6iqLp08ptq14qm4ppu9hrdGUU3klxE77Psn+7El6Cv3R8/asdfasdfaksdjhfiqwezhfknabsdfiugasdkf33==\\', \\'SigningCertUrl\\': \\'https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-ashk38dn298djhxo8he2lknfO.pem\\', \\'UnsubscribeUrl\\': \\'https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1:823baaf4-93b6-499a-944e-c99e1a6b1fb5\\', \\'MessageAttributes\\': {}}}]}",
                "Timestamp":"2020-03-02T00:20:06.458Z",
                "SignatureVersion":"1",
                "SigningCertUrl":"https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-d3iiiffndoendii3mmmdi3.pem",
                "UnsubscribeUrl":"https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456:sns-topic-dam-poc-new-import1:823baaf4-93b6-499a-944e-c99e1a6b1fb5",
                "MessageAttributes":{

                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can see the bucket name in `Message` 
This is my python code:

```
import boto3
def newImportHandler(event, context):
    print("__________")
    print(event)
    print("__________")
    simple1 = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    print('Simple 1 '+simple1)
    simple2 = simple1['Records'][0]
    print('Simple 2 '+simple2)
```

simple1 is a string! so this code fails!

Comment: Try `message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])` and then access `message['Records'][0]`.

Comment: I have already tried that, once I have done the json load, the variable 'message' turns out to be a string. So message['Records'] fails with string indices must be integer ...

Comment: I think you have to run `json.loads` again, as you have Message embeded in other Message. So need to `json.loads` internal message as well.

Comment: This message is malformed. Unfortunately json.load fails with: "JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:"

Comment: You have to play with that, us you have lots of escaped characters, e.g. ` \"Message\":\"{\\\\\"Service\\\\\":\\\\\"`

Comment: This worked fine for me with S3 to SNS to Lambda. With basic settings, the message embedded in the event seemed normal, did not have all of the escaping that you show (the \\\\), and my earlier suggestion for how to access the S3 event within the SNS event worked fine. Are you definitely just S3 to SNS to Lambda?

Answer (score 11):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created an **Amazon S3 bucket**
- Created an **Amazon SNS Topic** and modified permissions to accept requests from the bucket (taken from [Example Walkthrough: Configure a Bucket for Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html))
- Created an **AWS Lambda function** and subscribed it to the SNS topic
- Configured an **Amazon S3 event** on the bucket to send a message to the SNS topic
- Tested by uploading a file to the bucket

The Lambda code worked fine for me:

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    bucket = message['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = message['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    ...
```

Comment: For others who copy and paste this code, note there are trailing close parens at the end of the lines to set the bucket and key vars that should be removed. It's an easy enough fix, but took me a second to figure out the syntax error, hopefully this comment will save you a minute or so.

Comment: Fixed, thanks! BTW, if you have sufficient reputation, feel free to edit answers to fix errors like this.

Comment: I had no idea I could edit others peoples answers. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving an error for this too, and, according to the AWS documentation for processing a lambda event containing an SNS message, this code should be a starting point:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    print("From SNS: " + message)
    return message
```

But, as of the time of me writing this, the actual format of the event requires accessing the message like this:

```
string_msg = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
sns_msg = json.loads(string_msg)
```

and then, for the S3 event data:

```
s3_event_data = sns_msg['Records'][0]['s3']
```

The actual 'Message' entry within the event dictionary remains stringified JSON that needs to be loaded to get to the actual S3 event data.